# graphing tshark data using R and xts

Tags: r, xts

I am new to R and xts and have no clue how to code what I am after.
I have a data set that I wish to graph using R and xts

Using tshark and io stat I can produce a bytes/mbps per interval to analyse burst periods in a very detailed manor, the only thing missing from this is a graphical representation of the capture period.

**EDIT**
I noticed a decimal was missing from the mbps column, I have added this now

The dataset is as follows (truncated);

```
      ms    bytes    mbps
1     0.00   1880     1.504
2     0.01      0        0
3     0.02      0        0
4     0.03      0        0
5     0.04      0        0
6     0.05      0        0
7     0.06      0        0
8     0.07      0        0
9     0.08      0        0
10    0.09      0        0
11    0.10      0        0
12    0.11      0        0
13    0.12      0        0
14    0.13      0        0
15    0.14      0        0
16    0.15      0        0
17    0.16      0        0
18    0.17      0        0
19    0.18      0        0
20    0.19      0        0
21    0.20      0        0
22    0.21   3566    2.8528
23    0.22  54160    43.328
24    0.23  15954   12.7632
25    0.24      0        0
```

ms is the interval time period in steps of 10ms with associated bytes and mbps for that time period

I have read the file into a data frame using;

```
mydata <- read.table("d:/pcaps/tx-stats.txt",sep=",", header=FALSE, col.names=c("ms","bytes","mbps"))
```

It seems xts needs my ms column to be a time series but I am unsure how to get the interval period converted to meet this need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
I'd like to produce a series of graphs as shown [on this site](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/charting/) with the line graph showing mbps with a bar graph showing the bytes.

I know using chartSeries, addMACD and addBBand will achieve what I am after I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to get my data readable by xts.

** EDIT **

This is the code I used in the end

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

#dat <- head(read.table("d:/pcaps/tx-stats-1sec.txt",sep=",", header=FALSE, col.names=c("sec","bytes","mbps")),10000)
dat <- head(read.table("d:/pcaps/tx-stats-10ms.txt",sep=",", header=FALSE, col.names=c("sec","bytes","mbps")),100000)
#dat <- read.table("d:/pcaps/tx-stats.txt",sep=",", header=FALSE, col.names=c("ms","bytes","mbps"))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + ggtitle("******** WAN Mbps Transmitted") + theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold"))
gg <- gg + geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=sec, y=mbps, colour='mbps'))
gg <- gg + geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=sec, y=mean(dat$mbps), colour='avg'))
gg <- gg + geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=sec, y=1, colour='max'))
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0.005))
#gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(label=comma, limits=c(0, 1))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(label=comma)
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour='red'))
gg1 <- gg

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + ggtitle("******** WAN Bytes Transferred") + theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold"))
gg <- gg + geom_bar(data=dat, aes(x=sec, y=bytes, colour='bytes'),stat="identity")
gg <- gg + geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=sec, y=mean(dat$bytes), colour="avg"))
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(label=comma)
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour='red'))
gg2 <- gg

grid.arrange(gg1, gg2, ncol=1, heights=c(0.65, 0.35))

mean(dat$mbps)
summary(dat$bytes)
summary(dat$mbps)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this without worrying about `xts` initially:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=ms, y=mbps))
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0.005))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(label=comma, limits=c(0, 150000))
gg1 <- gg

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_bar(data=dat, aes(x=ms, y=bytes), stat="identity")
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(label=comma, limits=c(0, 100000))
gg2 <- gg

grid.arrange(gg1, gg2, ncol=1, heights=c(0.7, 0.3))
```

[image]

I left off quite a bit of `theme` formatting to reduce complexity and to not waste cycles if this isn't what you're looking for. A great deal of those combined charts can be tweaked to get the line + bar view in some of your linked charts.

Comment: this looks promising,  plugging in 65000 odd lines iof data however is returning the following exception

`Error: Results must be all atomic, or all data frames
In addition: Warning message:
In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect`

Comment: i found rerunning the following resulted in a graphic even with 65000 rows
`grid.arrange(gg1, gg2, ncol=1, heights=c(0.65, 0.35))`

Thank you for your help.